# Codemirror textarea editor need to enable only on previous selection

Tags: html, codemirror, ui-codemirror

I'm using codemirror to convert my textarea into editor, but there is another problem is that I need to enable that textarea field only on the base of previous input select field selection. How can I do it?

Here are code snippets:

Textarea field:

```
<textarea cols="1200" rows="10" id="nfTextArea" disabled="disabled" class="form-control" name="notfound_template_content"></textarea>
```

Previous Selection Field:

```
<div class="field_group html1"><label title="HTML."> Include 404 Template </label>
                                            <select name="nf_template" class="form-control" value="" type="text" onchange="notFound()">
                                                <option value="other"> Choose...</option>
                                                <option value="true"> Yes </option>
                                                <option value="false"> No </option>
                                            </select>
                                            <span class="help-block"> Select yes if you want to create 404 Template.</span>
                                        </div>
```

Javascript function to enable textarea field on the base of selection:

```
 //function to enable 404 template
    function notFound(){
        var $content = $('select[name="404_template"] option:selected').val();
        switch ($content) {
            case 'true':
                $('textarea[name="notfound_template_content"]').attr("disabled", false);
                break;
            case 'false':
                $('textarea[name="notfound_template_content"]').attr("disabled", true);
            default:
                $('textarea[name="notfound_template_content"]').attr("disabled", false);
                break;
        }
    }
```

Codemirror Function:

```
var myCodeMirror = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(nfTextArea,{
lineNumbers: true,
mode: 'htmlmixed',
theme : 'monokai',
enterMode: 'keep',
indentUnit: 4,
matchBrackets: true,
gutters: ["CodeMirror-lint-markers", "CodeMirror-linenumbers"],
styleActiveLine: true, /* Addon */
onCursorActivity: function() {
      editor.addLineClass(hlLine, null);
      hlLine = editor.addLineClass(editor.getCursor().line, "CodeMirror-    activeline-background");
   }
});
myCodeMirror.focus();
myCodeMirror.setCursor({line: 3});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to give you some hints:

put your CodeMirror codes inside function, like:

```
function Create_Codemirror_textarea(){
   var myCodeMirror = ........
   ....
}
```

and execute function when select field changes:

```
      .............
        case 'true':
               $('textarea[name="notfound_template_content"]').attr("disabled", false);
               Create_Codemirror_textarea()
        case 'false':
               ................
```